# CSS Fixed sidebar in the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a two column responsive layout using bootstrap.

In the left column I want to place my content with the width of 100%/2, and in the right, a fixed sidebar with the width of 100%/3.

this is the css I used to my sidebar but in the fiddle I attached the sidebar is in left side and I want it to be in right side.

```
 #sidebar-wrapper {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #000;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
```

## Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/une5nhf4/

**How can I modify this to correspond to my needs ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-right: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/une5nhf4/5/)

Comment: When the sidebar is open, it moves the content (margin/padding)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so how can I make the right content takes 100%/3 in witdth and the left content 100%/2 ?

Comment: Content will have 50% and right sidebar 33%; so what will be in that remaining 17%? Blackhole? ;-)

Comment: @Legionar hahaha sorry I wanted to say right : 100%/3 and left : 100% - 100%/3